# dedupe script help

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table where I want to delete duplicate rows. The duplicate rows are based on the attributeID, section, keyid, productId, and value fields. Each duplicate row does have a unique ID, **productattributeID**.

The following script shows which rows are duplicated:

```
 select aa.attributeID,section,keyid,productID, value,count(*)
from productattribute PA
inner join AvailableAttribute AA on AA.AttributeID = PA.productID
group by aa.attributeID,section,keyid,productID, value
having count(*)>1
```

I am struggling to write a script which will delete all but one of each row.
Can any one help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
declare @productattribute as table(productattributeID int,section varchar(20),keyid int,productId int,value  varchar(20))
declare @AvailableAttribute as table(attributeID int)

insert into @productattribute values(1,'a',10,20,'v')
insert into @productattribute values(2,'a',10,20,'v')
insert into @productattribute values(3,'a',10,20,'v')
insert into @productattribute values(4,'b',150,208,'vb')
insert into @productattribute values(5,'b',150,208,'vb')
insert into @productattribute values(6,'b',150,208,'vb')
insert into @productattribute values(7,'a',8,20,'v')
insert into @productattribute values(8,'a',10,19,'v')

insert into @AvailableAttribute values(20)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(20)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(20)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(208)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(208)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(208)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(20)
insert into @AvailableAttribute values(19)

select * from @productattribute 

delete from @productattribute where productattributeID not in
(
    select MIN(productattributeID) from @productattribute 
        where exists
        (
             select * from 
                    (select section,keyid,productID,value,attributeID
                        from @productattribute inner join @AvailableAttribute on attributeID = productId
                            group by attributeID,section,keyid,productId,value) X 
                    where X.attributeID=attributeID and X.keyid=keyid and X.productId=productId and X.section=section and X.value=value
        ) group by section,keyid,productId,value
)

select * from @productattribute
```